# How to create a volume with given size in Flocker?

Tags: docker, flocker

I am very new to Flocker and I have created a setup by Vagrant ([see here](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/volume-plugins-demo)) but I am not finding any command like flockerctl/flocker-volumes to create a volume with given size.

Comment: Any details about your set up? Have you seen [Flocker's installation instructions](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by manually installing the flockerctl ([see here](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/flocker-features/flockerctl.html)) in the controller node and then I created the user certificate by flocker-ca command. Later I exported the environment variable to use the flockerctl.

Answer (score 1):

Flocker has a few ways of creating the size of a volume.

1. by REST API. There is a "create dataset" api and use the `maximum_size` attribute in bytes for how large of a volume.
2. Via `docker volume` cli. When you have the `flocker-docker-plugin` working with flocker, simply run `docker volume create -d flocker --name myvol -o size=10gb`
3. (unsupported/experimental) use FlockerCTL.